# Python override __str__ outside of class definition

Tags: python, class

Say I have a module that I've imported that works fine but doesn't provide a good `__str__` method and I want to add one.

In some hybrid language:

```
from foo import Foo

Foo.prototype._str__ = function myNIcePrintFunction(){

}
```

How do I do this please in Python please?

Comment: A module? Or a class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can first define a function, and then monkey-patch it.

Like:

```
def foostr(self):
    return 'A foo str'

Foo.__str__ = foostr
```

Or with a *lambda expression*:

```
Foo.__str__ = lambda self: 'Another foo str'
```

There is however a small difference in the fact that this method will have a different `Foo.__str__.__name__`, etc. But the `str(..)` builtin function will work as expected. As [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681456/python-override-str-outside-of-class-definition/52681499?noredirect=1#comment92291383_52681499) says, we can use the `wrap` function from `functools` to preserve most meta-data:

```
from functools import wraps

def foostr(self):
    return 'A foo str'

Foo.__str__ = wraps(Foo.__str__)(foostr)
```

But then `Foo.__str__.__qualname__` will for example result in `'superfoo.__str__'` (with `superfoo` the first class in the *method resolution order (MRO)* of `Foo` that implemented `__str__`).

For example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...   pass
... 
>>> str(Foo())
'<__main__.Foo object at 0x7f807046e668>'
>>> Foo.__str__ = lambda self: 'another Foo str'
>>> str(Foo())
'another Foo str'
```

If you have access to the implementation of the `Foo` class, it is however better to just define a `__str__` function in the class, and not *monkey patch* it later in the process.

Comment: You can use `functools.wrap` to preserve (most of) the metadata: `Foo.__str__ = functools.wraps(Foo.__str__)(foostr)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can override any class function like this, while maintaining the original functionalities:

```
class a():
    pass

def monkey(fn):
    def newfn(self,*args, **kw):
        print('hijacked!')
        return fn(self,*args, **kw)
    return newfn

a.__str__ = monkey(a.__str__)


b = a()

print(str(b))

>>> hijacked!                                                                                                                                                                            
>>> <__main__.a object at 0x7f61f19faa58>
```